# Automatic Execution Custom Maven Plugin

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin

I have implemented a Maven 2 plugin.

I have that definiton for my Mojo:

```
/**
 * Goal which combines files.
 *
 * @goal combine
 * @phase compile
 */
public class CombineMojo extends AbstractMojo {
```

I have to add this into my project (which uses plugin) pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>base-project</groupId>
    <artifactId>base-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>combine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <configuration>
                    <input>src/input.html</input>
                    <output>html/output.html</output>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>combine-maven-plugin</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>combine</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

However what should I do automatically execute it instead of defining at pom.xml. I tries adding

```
@execute ...
```

into my Mojo definition however it didn't work. By the way should I define an id, what is need for it?

Comment: Can you show the complete pom file of your test project? Furthermore a plugin can not be executed automatically it must be bound to a life-cycle-phase.

Comment: Do you get any error/message during the execution of your test project ?

Comment: @khmarbaise A plugin **can** be executed automatically, but only specific ones defined for specific packaging types: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57061848/1548776

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maven plugin can only be executed if it's bound a [life-cycle phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) in Maven.

Comment: A plugin **can** be executed automatically, but only specific ones defined for specific packaging types: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57061848/1548776 (so not possible for custom plugins [except for custom packaging types]).