# Binding a custom Maven plugin to a default phase

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have a custom Maven plugin that I'm trying to bind to the `package` phase by default.  I've tried every combination of using the `@Mojo` annotation along with the `@Execute` annotation, but it doesn't seem to auto bind.

The only way I manage to get my plugin to work is by defining it like this:

```
@Mojo(name = "put")
public class SSHMojo extends AbstractMojo {
```

And then in my project using the plugin, defining an execution.  I'd like to avoid having to add the `<executions>` every time I want to use my plugin.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.patrickgrimard</groupId>
  <artifactId>ssh-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>put</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <serverId>devopsmtl</serverId>
    <host>example.com</host>
    <remoteDirectory>/srv/www</remoteDirectory>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My full plugin pom can be found at https://github.com/pgrimard/ssh-maven-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57061848/1548776

Answer (score 3):

Hi simply use the following:

```java
@Mojo( name = "put", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PACKAGE )
```

Apart from that i would suggest to use a newer version of maven-plugin-api (3.0 at least)...

Comment: I've upgraded the maven-plugin-api to 3.3.3 and added the defaultPhase, but it still doesn't run my plugin unless I specify the execution in my pom.

Comment: Show the example pom which you are using for it...Apart from that you know [wagon-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/)

Answer (score 2):

1. Use annotation attribute `defaultPhase` (like already mentioned by khmarbaise):

```
@Mojo(name = "put", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PACKAGE)
public class SSHMojo extends AbstractMojo { ... }
```

2. In the `pom.xml` of the consuming Maven project you can leave away the reference to the phase after this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.patrickgrimard</groupId>
  <artifactId>ssh-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <!-- <phase>package</phase> --><!-- needed no longer -->
      <goals>
        <goal>put</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  ...
```